Flutter share_plus package opening quick share directly instead of options
I am relatively new user of flutter. I had been using the share_plus package in order to export files via the Share.shareXfiles. Recently, I used a new emulator with API 35 and now the export goes directly to quick share, and I don't want that, how do I only enable email?
I used the share_plus packages methods in order to do it in the past. I looked at pub dev to see if there was anything but I might be blind.
This is a function I use:
Future<void> shareGeoJsonFile(String filePath) async {
  // Share the file externally
  await Share.shareXFiles(
    [XFile(filePath)],
    subject: 'Exported survey data',
    text: 'Here is the GeoJSON data for the survey.',
  );
}


It was a stupid mistake, the app had a mail app that didnt show up but adding gmail made the option show up
